# The banner at the top of my webpage repeats

Tags: html, css

Ok, so my website, http://ichion.tk, I have a banner, it repeats. What I'm asking is how to fix this. Here is my code for it:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
div#title {
  background-image: url("banner.png");
  color:yellow;
  height:120px;
  width:100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id=title>

</div>
```

If it makes a difference, it's the same in both Google Chrome and Safari. I don't know about how it looks in other browsers.

Comment: great `ncurses` application :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you don't want the banner to be stretched at all, so I would avoid using `background-size`. Instead, define a `background-color` of `black`:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-color: black;
```

Here is a screenshot of the result:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why I never tried that. Well, learn a new thing every day!

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```
div#title { 
    background: #00ff00 url("banner.gif") no-repeat fixed center; 
}
```

Read more here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp

Comment: This doesn't really address OP's specific scenario. Also, this would result in a centered background, which I don't think the OP is going for.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
```